# Real analysis question - proving from first principes

Tags: real-analysis

Prove from first principles that if $x_n$ $\to$ *x* as *n* $\to$ $\infty$, then |$x_n$| $\to$ |*x*|

So far I have

We want $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$\forall n \geq N \implies  ||x_n| - |x|| < \varepsilon$

$||x_n| - |x|| \leq |x_n - x|$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$||x_n| -|x||\leq |x_n-x|$ [This is called the reverse triangle inequality].